# Set Organizational Unit by IP Address in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ip-address, organizational-unit

Our AD is a mess, and I've been trying to look for a way to automatically assign computers/workstations to an Organizational Unit based on their IP address. I've had no luck, though, in finding any information on how to do so.

Is there a way to do this? If so, how does one go about assigning computers to an OU based on their IP?

Comment: Do these computers roam between them, or are the IP address ranges based on something like geographical location? Also, what is the actual problem that you're trying to solve by sorting these computers into OUs by IP, because there are probably better ways to go about it.

Comment: Just trying to set client-side targeting for WSUS by IP range, as the IP ranges are based on geographic locations. I think your answer helps quite a bit. I'm not too familiar with AD, as I generally just deal with Linux servers and such.

Comment: Then what you want is to use the targetting policy with a site-based GPO and set up the subnets in AD Sites and Services. @Massimo's opening statement is the answer to your problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why would you want to do such a thing? If your goal is to apply specific GPOs to computers based on their network location, you can accomplish this a lot more easily by linking GPOs to Active Directory sites.

If you *really* have a good reason for doing this, there is no built-in way; you can probably hack something with PowerShell along these lines:

- Get a computer from AD
- Query DNS for its IP address
- Move it to the OU you want

But I strongly advise you against this; have a good look at the *actual* problem you're trying to solve, and you'll very likely find a better way to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'd have to script something like this, but it could certainly be done.  If you really want to go wild you could run it as a login script (computer) via GPO and have it moved about automatically if the computer is moved to a different subnet.

Script would use something like these plus verbiage to identify where you want to send it:

```
$ips = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses("hostname-here")
```

`Insert logic here`

```
$hostname = get-adcomputer("hostname-here")

Move-ADObject '$hostname' -TargetPath 'OU=Accounting,DC=Fabrikam,DC=com'
```

Comment: A startup scripts runs in the security context of the computer's system account, while a login script runs in the security context of the logging-on user; computer accounts (usually) don't have permissions to move objects around in AD, and neither do users, unless they are domain admins.